# Solved: Cannot Post Error 400 when posting user details on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, post, axios

I was just wondering if a second pair of eyes can see what I am missing or doing wrong.
I am doing a POST request to a server for a login form. Thank you very much :)

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setData({
      ...data,
      [e.target.name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userData = {
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
    };

   axios
      .post(
        "https://myserver.net/api/auth/login",
      userData,
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.status);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response);
          console.log("server responded");
        } else if (error.request) {
          console.log("network error");
        } else {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
  };
```

The error I am getting is 400 and on the network tab is this: `{"email":["The Email field is required."],"password":["The Password field is required."]},`

Then an example on the input of the email is:

```js
            <input
                id="email"
                name="email"
                type="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                required
                value={data.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder="Email address"
              />
```

Comment: I know too little about axios, but are you sure that the `const userdata` gets set in the `handleSubmit` event before it is used as a parameter  to `axios.post`?

Comment: So on the payload on the network tab is showing the values that I am entering, the email and the password, and adding a console.log straight after the ``handleSubmit`` is showing the values of the input that I entered... mm...

Comment: Just a typo. Move your `userData` out of the config object, eg `axios.post(url, userData, { headers: { ... } })`. See [`axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config)

Comment: Hey @Phil is still the same error, but good shout cause it should be outside

Comment: @VickyR could you please [edit] your question to match what you changed?